# Displaying Latitude and Longitude on Google Map Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to show latitude and longitude lines/grid on a java script code I created using google maps api but I am unable to show the exact latitude and longitude positions. I tried to use overlay map type which shows a pixel grid but not a latitude and longitude grid

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay , this what I used

Comment: perhaps this might be helpful: [HowTo display latitude longitude grid on Google Maps?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/wRuOuecsv6I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the overlayMapType-example you may calculate the Point of the top-left corner of the tile based on the tile-coordinate and convert this point into a LatLng via the method `fromPointToLatLng` of the map-projection:

```js
function initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.549878, 13.425209)
  });

  function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
  }

  CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {

    var f = Math.pow(2, zoom),
        t = this.tileSize,
        w = t.width,
        h = t.height,
        n = ownerDocument.createElement('div'),

        //calculate the point of the top-left tile-corner
        p = new google.maps.Point(
          ((w * (coord.x / f)) + w) % w, 
          ((h * (coord.y / f)) + h) % h
        );

    //dont draw redundant tiles
    if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= f) return n;

    //print coordinates
    n.innerHTML = '<span>' +
      map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(p).toUrlValue() +
      '</span>';
    n.style.width = w + 'px';
    n.style.height = h + 'px';
    n.className = 'tile';
    return n;
  };
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
    0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.tile {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.tile span {
  background: #fff;
  font: 12px Monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to display consecutive latitudes and longitudes ,I mean rather than having some integer number with decimal places we just show consecutive whole numbers like 55,56,57 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this library does what you want?

https://github.com/alexcheng1982/google-maps-gridlines